# Onbeforeunload Event calling

Tags: vue.js

I am new to vuejs. Does anyone help me?
If I click the browser refresh button, I need to show the popup. So I used below code here.

```
I am using the code like,

window.onbeforeunload=function(){
 return "Your work will be lost.";
}
```

I used this function under the beforeMount() lifecycle instance in a single page. But, this popup showed the multiple pages, when I click the browser refresh button. I want to show this pop up in a single page. Can Anyone help me??

Comment: i understood that you want to show a popup that alert the user to do not reload the page because he will loose his work? if he click cancel button he will stay in the page?

Comment: @boussadjra brahim Thanks for the reply. My question was to call the event in a single page. I used event in a single page router but it shown in all router pages.Can you give me a solution?

Comment: maybe i can give a solution if you provide more code snippet

Comment: @boussadjra brahim 
I used this code in a single page like sample.vue. But, the popup shown in multiple pages. Herewith, I mentioned the link here.
https://codepen.io/vpriya95/pen/mGqOBw

Comment: the code that you shared it contains only this snippet `beforeMount(){
 window.onbeforeunload=function(){
  return "Your work will be lost.";
}
}`

Comment: @boussadjra brahim 
Good morning 
Herewith I mentioned my browser refresh button the code here
https://codepen.io/vpriya95/pen/eLeLqP

Comment: good morning bro, try `  beforeCreate() { 
      confirm("Your work will be lost.");
  }`

Answer (score 2):

I see this is an old post, but maybe this will help you in the future or others. As mentioned above, it would help a lot to see the actual code implementation, but maybe this will help.

```
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    shouldPrevent: false
  }),

  beforeMount() {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.preventNav)
  },

  beforeDestroy() {
    // Don't forget to clean up event listeners
    window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", this.preventNav)
  },

  methods: {
    preventNav(e) {
      if (!this.shouldPrevent) return
      e.preventDefault()
      e.returnValue = ""
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: I know this is old. For anyone looking at this answer it should read `window.removeEventListener` and not `document.removeEventListener`

Comment: FYI in Vue.js 3.0.0+ beforeDestroy is deprecated, and you should use beforeUnmount instead.